How to locally save radio buttons selection status of HTML as .TXT file and load back the selection status
I am developing a simple html form to collect different users dataset using text input fields and radio buttons. After researching, I found a good piece of script to save to- and load from .txt file using two textbox fields as posted on this site at this link. I would like to build up on this script and add the state of (checked/unchecked) the following radio buttons:
<input type="radio" id="jan" name="Month" value="January" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" id="dec" name="Month" value="December" />

Along with the var textboxes, the bellow variable saves the value of checked radio button but it loads the value back to a textbox rather than maintaining the checked state of the radio buttons
var radioState = document.querySelector('input[name="Month"]:checked').value;

I would appreciate any support on this


var separator = "_*_";
var textBoxes = ["inputTextToSave1", "inputTextToSave2", "Month"];

function saveTextAsFile() {
  var textToSave = "";
  for (var a = 0; a < textBoxes.length; a++) {
    textToSave += a < textBoxes.length - 1 ? document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value + separator : document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value + radioState;
  }
  var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {
    type: "text/plain"
  });
  var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
  var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
  downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText() {
  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
    var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    var textesArray = textFromFileLoaded.split(separator);
    for (var a = 0; a < textBoxes.length; a++) {
      document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value = textesArray[a];
    }
  };
  fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text to Save:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <textarea id="inputTextToSave1" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <textarea id="inputTextToSave2" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <input type="radio" id="id_june" name="Month" value="June" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" id="id_december" name="Month" value="December" />
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
    <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></td>
    <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
    <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
    <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>




I'm not seeing where radioState is referenced anywhere else in your code. Where are you seeing that its value is loaded back into a textbox?

Have you checked your dev console for errors? Your snippet has an error:  textToSave += a < textBoxes.length - 1 ? document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value + separator : document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value; => you don't have any elements with id="Month"

Had just missed that and just included along with the separator

@mykaf, I was trying to call the variable rarioState by name. The ids are id_june and id_december. I had tried to include the ids in the textbox array as 'var textBoxes = ["inputTextToSave1", "inputTextToSave2", "id_june", "id_december"];' but it is till not working

Is there an error in your dev console? What steps are you taking to debug this? After updating textBoxes with the actual radio IDs, I was able to download a txt.

Main changes:

Updated the saveAsTextFile function to include the value of your radio button
loadFileAsText function also now loads the radio button value
Removed month from textboxes array because it is handled separately

Please note: The file will not save if you use the snippet execution below, you'll need to just drop this into a local html file and try it out.


    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form with File Save and Load</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Text to Save:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <textarea id="inputTextToSave1" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <textarea id="inputTextToSave2" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Month:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="id_june" name="Month" value="June" checked="checked" />
                <label for="id_june">June</label>
                <input type="radio" id="id_december" name="Month" value="December" />
                <label for="id_december">December</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
            <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></td>
            <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
            <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
            <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        var separator = "_*_";
        var textBoxes = ["inputTextToSave1", "inputTextToSave2"];

        function saveTextAsFile() {
            var textToSave = "";
            for (var a = 0; a < textBoxes.length; a++) {
                textToSave += document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value + separator;
            }
            
            // Add the selected radio button value
            var selectedMonth = document.querySelector('input[name="Month"]:checked').value;
            textToSave += selectedMonth;

            var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {
                type: "text/plain"
            });
            var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
            var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
            downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
            downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
            downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
            downloadLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            downloadLink.click();
        }

        function destroyClickedElement(event) {
            document.body.removeChild(event.target);
        }

        function loadFileAsText() {
            var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                var textesArray = textFromFileLoaded.split(separator);
                for (var a = 0; a < textBoxes.length; a++) {
                    document.getElementById(textBoxes[a]).value = textesArray[a];
                }
                
                // Set the radio button based on the loaded value
                var loadedMonth = textesArray[textesArray.length - 1];
                document.querySelector(`input[name="Month"][value="${loadedMonth}"]`).checked = true;
            };
            fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>



